# unable to select data for certain fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql query which selects data from whole table with date ranges but the problem is that when I search for another field in it with same user id it doesnot work as expected.

Suppose, `user id 30 adds 3000 deposit and user id 44 adds 888 deposit`.

So my problem is that when I fetch the data with deposit for `user id 30` it also fetches the `deposit of user id 44`.

The query I am working on is:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_finanace` 
WHERE `transaction_date` BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2015-05-14' 
AND `user_id` = '30' OR `finance_type` = 'Deposit'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `AND` instead of `OR` . This should be -

```
AND `user_id` = '30' AND `finance_type` = 'Deposit'
```

The query will be -

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_finanace` WHERE `transaction_date` BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2015-05-14' AND `user_id` = '30' AND `finance_type` = 'Deposit'
```

Comment: But that will not pick complete select data as well. I want to select complete data of that user id 30 having its deposit as well.

Comment: What are the conditions and table structure?

Comment: I want to fetch complete data of that user id 30 with some his deposit separately as well. Something like sum (deposit) as total deposit like statements.

Comment: you want the count of deposits of that user for a particular time period?

Comment: yes excatly count of that user only.. when i used and it select only one row when i use OR it select other deposit data as well.

Comment: Why not simply do `select count(deposite) as total_dep from tbl_finanace WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2015-05-14' AND user_id = '30' AND finance_type = 'Deposit'`

Comment: use braces () to separate the conditions

Comment: No need of `()` for this.

Comment: Sorry deposit is not field name its the data. I mean like this `finance_type = 'Deposit'`